# docker-compose volume live edit

Tags: docker, docker-compose, local, edit, docker-volume

I am having some trouble to edit code live with Prestashop.

Reference: https://github.com/mattiamari/docker-prestashop1.7-php7-fpm

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    prestashop:
      build: 
        context: prestashop
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
        args:
        - PRESTASHOP_VERSION=1.7.6.2
      environment:
        PS_DOMAIN: "localhost:8081"
        DB_SERVER: db
        DB_PORT: "3306"
        DB_USER: prestashop
        DB_PASSWORD: prestashop
        DB_NAME: prestashop
        DB_CLEAR: '0'
        DB_CREATE: '1'
        DB_PREFIX: "ps_"
        PS_DIR_INSTALL: install1234
        PS_DIR_ADMIN: admin1234
        PS_LANGUAGE: en
        PS_TIMEZONE: "Europe/London"
        PS_SHOP_NAME: "test shop"
        PS_SHOP_COUNTRY: en
        PS_FIRSTNAME: John
        PS_LASTNAME: Doe
        PS_PASSWORD: testshop123
        PS_EMAIL: "jdoe@foo.bar"
        PS_NEWSLETTER: '0'
        PS_SSL: '0'
        PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT: 256M
        PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME: "200"
        PHP_MAX_INPUT_TIME: "60"
      expose:
      - "9000"
      volumes:
      - app:/app
      depends_on:
      - db
      restart: unless-stopped
    web:
      build: web
      environment:
        PS_DOMAIN: "localhost:8081"
        PS_DIR_INSTALL: install1234
        PS_DIR_ADMIN: admin1234
      ports:
      - "8081:80"
      # - "443:443"
      volumes:
      - app:/app:rw
      depends_on:
      - prestashop
      restart: unless-stopped
    db:
      image: mariadb:latest
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: supercow
        MYSQL_DATABASE: prestashop
        MYSQL_USER: prestashop
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: prestashop
      volumes:
      - ./db/config:/etc/mysql/conf.d
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
      restart: unless-stopped
volumes:
    app:
      driver: local
      driver_opts:
        type: none
        o: bind
        device: ${PWD}/httpdocs/current
    db-data:
```

I would like to have access to /app from my local, what I am doing wrong ?

Is there a way to share the content live for development tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently using a named volume for your `/app` mount instead of a file system mount (which you actually are using for `./db/config:/etc/mysql/conf.d`).

Switch your `/app` mount to the following in your `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
      volumes:
        - ./app:/app
```

Once you do that, you will be able to interact with that folder from your file system relative to your `docker-compose.yml` file.

--

The named volume you are using also lives on the file system but is not meant to be interacted with directly. If you inspect your container, you can see where the files are and can manipulate with sudo privileges. Here is an example of my elasticsearch container.

```
$ docker inspect elasticsearch | grep -i Volume
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": [],
                "Type": "volume",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/kibana_es_data/_data",
            "Volumes": {
```